# How to check ratio of usage elements from nutrion solution for lettuce

Tags: hydroponic

I measure `ppm` for my hydroponics system. And I would like to know a proportion of every element (Calcium Nitrogen) etc. that my plant is absorbing.
For example I have a nutrion solution which contains 6% of Nitrogen, by 800ppm, by 30L of water could I practically get percentage of Nitrogen in water when my ppm drops to 600, when I know the constant of absorption of Nitrogen by lettuce?
If yes, is there some kind of table, or datasheet for this?